# How to show the following inequality, $H_{2^n}\geq n/2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k $

I want to show that $H_{2^n}\geq n/2$ for every $n$ greater than or equal to 1.

How should I proceed?

Comment: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) page on harmonic series contains at least 2 proofs

Answer (score 1):

For instance by induction.

Hint for the inductive step:

$$H_{2^{n+1}}=H_{2^{n}}+\frac1{2^n+1}+\dots+\frac1{2^{n+1}}=H_{2^{n}}+\underbrace{\frac1{2^n+1}+\dots+\frac1{2^n+2^n}}_{2^n\:\text{terms}}.$$